# multiple input files with complex operations in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have just started using ffmpeg for one of my project. I have very limited knowledge of ffmpeg.

I need a help on below problem. Thanks in advance.

I have two files:-

1. Audio File
2. Video File

I want to generate single file after performing below operations:-

- trim the audio file to custom start and stop point.
- merge audio and video file to a single file (video file is of same size)
- apply speed filter on the generated file.

I am able to achieve the output but with three different ffmpeg commands due to which it is taking lot of time. I want to achieve the all there tasks in a single ffmpeg command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) and [atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo) (or [rubberband](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband)) filters. This example will double the speed:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 3 -t 10 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[1:a]atempo=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest output.mp4
```

- `-ss 3` will skip beginning 3 seconds in `audio.mp3`.
- `-t 10` will limit `audio.mp3` duration to 10 seconds.
- `-shortest` will make `output.mp4` duration the same as the shortest output stream duration.